# Update record on database in MVC4

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

need some help here..

Aim: Update record on database in MVC4

I have a Accordian view with two buttons #1.Edit #2.save.. 
Till now what had done is..

using following code i have fetch data from database to corresponding text boxes.

Step 1: Data filled in textboxes are property set as readonly once edit button clicked text boxes will set as editable.

Step 2:if i change data and click save button that should update on database

Problem:

While updating the data in the database updated data is adding in the new row as a new data.
But i need the existing data should be updated

View:

```
<body>

    <div id='cssmenu'>
        <ul>
            <li class='active'></li>
            <li class='has-sub'>
                <a href='#'><span>Profile</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <form method="post" >
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
                            @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)*@
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EmailID)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailID, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailID)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MobileNumber)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MobileNumber, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MobileNumber)
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                 <input type="button" id="btn" name="Edit" value="Edit"/>
                        <input type="submit" name="Save" id="Save" />
                        @*<input type="submit" name="Save" value="Save" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Save", "CU")'" />*@
               </form>
                </ul>
            </li>


             <li class='has-sub'>
                <a href='#'><span>Change Password</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href='#'><span>Company</span></a></li>
                    <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class='has-sub'>
                <a href='#'><span>Add Customer</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href='#'><span>Company</span></a></li>
                    <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>

@section scripts
{

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $("#btn").click(function () {
            $("#FirstName").removeAttr("readonly");
            $("#LastName").removeAttr("readonly");
            $("#EmailID").removeAttr("readonly");
            $("#MobileNumber").removeAttr("readonly");

        });

    </script>

    }
```

Controller

```
 public ActionResult AccountPanel(int id, string Save, string FirstName)
        {

            var profile = (from s in db.tblUsers
                               where s.UserTypeId == 3 && s.UserID == id
                               select new Profile
                               {
                                   FirstName = s.FirstName,
                                   LastName = s.LastName,
                                   EmailID = s.EmailID,
                                   MobileNumber = s.MobileNumber


                               }).FirstOrDefault();



                if (Save != null)
                {

                    using (var context = new SYTEntities())
                    {
                        var s = context.tblUsers.Where(a => a.UserID == id).FirstOrDefault();
                            s.FirstName = FirstName;
                            s.LastName = profile.LastName;
                            s.EmailID = profile.EmailID;
                            s.MobileNumber = profile.MobileNumber;

                            context.tblUsers.Add(s);

                            context.SaveChanges();


                    }


                }



                return View(profile);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update data in the database please change to below code.

```
if (Save != null)
{

    using (var context = new SYTEntities())
    {
        var s = context.tblUsers.Where(a => a.UserID == id).FirstOrDefault();
        s.FirstName = FirstName;
        s.LastName = profile.LastName;
        s.EmailID = profile.EmailID;
        s.MobileNumber = profile.MobileNumber;

        context.SaveChanges();

    }

}
```

remove `context.tblUsers.Add(s);`  from your code

Answer (score 1):

```
using (var context = new SYTEntities())
{
    var s = context.tblUsers.Where(a => a.UserID ==     id).FirstOrDefault();
    s.FirstName = FirstName;
    s.LastName = profile.LastName;
    s.EmailID = profile.EmailID;
    s.MobileNumber = profile.MobileNumber;

    // SET STATE TO CHANGED
    db.Entry(tblUsers).State = EntityState.Modified;

    context.SaveChanges();

}
```